# 'Response too large to return' error when using a destination table and 'Allow Large Results' option

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to perform a query which joins a table of about 1 mln rows with a smaller one and saving the results to a destination table via the BigQuery UI. I've checked the option 'Allow Large Results'. However after 30s it responds with 'Response too large to return.'. When I uncheck the option 'Allow Large Results' it works fine. (it runs then for about 5 mins).
I initially ran into this issue when running this query job using the BigQueryJava API in an automated process, using the same options.

The query runs also fine when I disable the options in the BigQuery UI.

So there is a workaround for me, but this query job ran fine until today with the 'Allow Large Results' option.

The query is basically is like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t2.d, t2.e
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN EACH table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.a = t2.a
```

Comment: Can you share the query? Does your JOIN use JOIN EACH? Do you have an ORDER BY?

Comment: I've added the query (in a generic form). It does contain a JOIN but no ORDER BY. I didn't expect the query to fail when using the 'Allow Large Results' option and succeed when not using this option.

Comment: This is unexpected. Do you have a job id for a failed query?

Comment: One of the failed jobs is job_e7eef062f4034e0b935cdc7c5959df05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in query preparation. We're working on a fix. 
Edited to add: This was fixed in 2013.

Comment: Have you fixed this bug?