# BigQuery - Join Each Error

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery is throwing a Join Each error even  though I am using Join Each:

My query:

```
SELECT MS.CUSIP
FROM MS
JOIN EACH MM
ON  MS.C = MM.C;
```

Error :

```
Error: Table too large for JOIN. Consider using JOIN EACH. For more details, please see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#joins
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a long term solution, but try turning off "Allow Large Results" and see if it work. I just tried that and it seems to work.

Comment: For some reason the exact same query worked -as is- today. Probably some caching issue?

Comment: I am getting the error still unless I turn off "Allow Large Results"

Comment: Now the response is too large to return so I need to turn the "allow large results" back on.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here:
['Response too large to return' error when using a destination table and 'Allow Large Results' option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767090/response-too-large-to-return-error-when-using-a-destination-table-and-allow-l)
This is a known bug, we hope to have a fix by end-of-day today.

Comment: I found out I had the error because I did not specify "GROUP EACH BY" in my subselect that was specify in the FROM part

Answer (score 0):

You could try reducing the size of table that you are joining like,

```
SELECT MS.CUSIP
FROM 
(
    SELECT CUSIP,C FROM MS
)
MS
JOIN EACH MM
ON  MS.C = MM.C;
```

Size of joining table is reduced as this has only 2 columns that are needed in the query.